# Rolling 12 months oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am writing a query in Oracle that I want to automate. I currently have a `where` clause that has the following:

```
TRAN.DATE BETWEEN 20160101 AND 20161231
```

I want the query to be a 12 month look back from the current date. I think I can do it if the date was in a date format using the following:

```
TRAN.DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
```

But the date format in the table is in an `integer` format. I have tried to the `TO_DATE` function but I can't get the format right.

Answer (score 2):

Yikes, you mean your database table literally has an integer of 20170104 (twenty million, one hundred seventy thousand, one hundred and four) and this represents the forth of Jan, this year?

Setting aside any concerns I have about this not being the best way to store a date, it's probably going to be easiest to write and also understand, if you convert your date to char and then to int:

```
WHERE DATECOLUMN BETWEEN
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12),'YYYYMMDD')) AND 
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD'))
```

There's no point getting clever and trying to deal with it as an integer math problem by subtracting 1200 or 10000 etc as a number because it'll make your query hard to understand and have no performance gain at all over a couple of number conversions as per this way

You'd be better off changing those dates to actual dates right now, before the codebase grows any bigger and someone decides it's a good idea to add more date columns stored as ints

Comment: This is the safer approach, because it will cope if `tran.date` contains numeric values which won't translate into dates. You're right that the column should be converted to DATE datatype.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
TO_DATE(TRAN.DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')  BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm),

> `TO_DATE` converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2
>   datatype to a value of DATE datatype

so you need to first cast `integer` column to `char` or any of the accepted datatype specified above, and then cast it to `DATE` as below.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(to_char(20160101),'YYYYMMDD') as DATE1 FROM DUAL
```

**Result**

```
DATE1
-------------------
01.01.2016 00:00:00
```

so you need to rewrite your query as below.

```
TO_DATE(to_char(TRAN.DATE),'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
```

Also if you need only date part, you amy also need to `trunc` `sysdate`.

You can check the demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/VGX74130)

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is fine providing there's no index on `tran.date` which needs to be used. And assuming that all the values in the column can be converted to dates - which the lessons of history tell us is not guaranteed.

Comment: so it would be better to transform ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) amd SYSDATE to this ineger format.